# How would I power and wire a raspbbery pi 4 and 20 servos?

Tags: power-supply, raspberry-pi, servo

I am trying to control two robotic arms with a raspberry pi 4. I will need to power the pi and 20 [SG90 servos](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07L2SF3R4). I am pretty new to electronics, so I am not very sure on how I am going to do this.

I am currently thinking of using 3 power supplys. I am thinking of using a power bank which outputs 5v through USB to USB-C to power the raspberry pi, and then one power supply for each of the arms. Each arm will have 10 servos.

I would like to know two things:

1. What power supply should I buy to power each arm? I would prefer an AA cell pack if that is possible but any rechargeable battery under $40 is fine.
2. How would I connect all the servos to the power supply? Do I need to use a breadboard?

Comment: How do you know the force & weight * length doesn't exceed the servo torque?

Comment: I'm not really sure - I am new to this. I think the SG90 servos should be good for controlling the fingers since the fingers don't need to apply to much force - the hand will be used for lifting and folding clothes. If you recommend I use a different brand of servos, please send a link and I'll look into it. I am planning on building a cardboard prototype and then 3D printing the final version. However, before I start, I need to figure out the electrical components to order from Amazon - that's why I am asking this question.

Comment: It's a basic Physics problem. Not all have the same load